# Shell aliases when launching programs from within a Desktop environment (Alt+F2) or window manager?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xorg, alias

I'm quite confused about how X runs its programs. As I understand it, much of the environment for programs run by the desktop environment (Gnome/XFCE/i3) is setup (traditionally) in `/etc/X11/xinit/Xinitrc` and other files like `/etc/X11/Xsession`.

If I wanted to have the path variables for X to have access to my `$HOME/bin`, I'd just enter the appropriate command into `/etc/X11/Xinitrc`. This appears to work under i3 (dmenu), gnome (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), etc. when I want to run executables from `$HOME/bin`.

However, I'm not able to give it access to aliases I create. I cannot add an alias like

```
alias ab='firefox'
```

to `xinitrc` and then expect to launch it using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Perhaps this has something to do with the way the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> launches programs. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are a bash (or whichever shell you are using) feature and have nothing to do with the graphical environment. Your DE has no knowledge and no access to your aliases.

This basically comes down to the difference between the shell (e.g. bash, zsh, sh or whatever) and the *graphical* shell (such as GNOME shell). The latter deals with running commands in your GUI and, despite the name, is not in any way related to the command line shell that you use in your terminals and where you define you aliases.

So, if you want to have alias-like functionality in your graphical shell, you should use links instead. For example, you could create links in your `~/bin` directory with the appropriate name that point to the executable you wish to call:

```
ln -s $(which firefox) ~/bin/ab
```

Now, you can run `firefox` by writing `ab` in the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> textbox.